# pandas object column with string and numerical duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1', '0', '1.0', '0.0', 1.0, 0.0, 'not_ind', np.nan]}).astype('O')
print(a['A'].unique())
```

The set of values is:

```
array(['1', '0', '1.0', '0.0', 1.0, 0.0, 'not_ind', nan], dtype=object)
```

I want to transform this `A` column to be set of:

```
array(['1.0', '0.0', 'not_ind', nan], dtype=object)
```

I can solve this problem with my custom code, but is there some elegant `pandas` functionality to deal with such cases?

I want to get rid of string<->numerical duplicates (retain only strings), preserve other string constants and preserve `nan` as np.nan constant, not string value 'nan'.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? I'm not able to comprehend the objective.

Comment: I want to get rid of string<->numerical duplicates, preserve other string constants and preserve `nan` as np.nan constant, not string value 'nan'

Comment: Do you need convert numeric to strings ?

Comment: ...yes @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible numeric values else strings if not possible convert by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
a['A'] = pd.to_numeric(a['A'], errors='coerce').fillna(a['A'])
print(a['A'].unique())
[1.0 0.0 'not_ind' nan]
```

If no replace non missing values to strings in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = pd.to_numeric(a['A'], errors='coerce').fillna(a['A'])

a['A'] = np.where(s.isna(), np.nan, s.astype(str))
print(a['A'].unique())
['1.0' '0.0' 'not_ind' nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`.

See more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).